# Calculating a submanifold of minimal values

Tags: optimization, nonconvex

I have a (numerical, noisy) function $f$ that I'd like to optimize (in 3 < dimension < 10).

The function $f$ has a fairly prominent valley/ravine structure due to physical symmetries present in the input data. To be more precise: there is a submanifold $V$ of low dimension (let's say 1 or 2) along which function values are close to the global minimum $x \in V$. I would like to approximate the submanifold $V$.

The problem of such valleys/ravines is well-known in the literature, any first course on numerical optimization will mention the Rosenbrock function. However, I keep coming up short when looking for methods of computing/parametrizing the valley itself. I guess I could look at the gradient flow and treat the valley as the slow manifold of that, but due to the fact that my valley potentially has lots of local minima due to noise, I don't expect this to work particularly well.

What is the most common way of dealing with this kind of problem?

Comment: Probably applying some filtering to the data you could come up with a function that does not have so much noise and/or local minima but the valley/ravine structure is still there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! You could do some Monte Carlo sampling, and choosing the lowest/highest 1% of your evaluations, all these samples will lie close to your submanifold. Since you are picking random samples, these are not sensitive to local minima/maxima. The percentage of your samples will act like a tolerance. That might at least help to localise it.

Comment: Sencond Idea: Find the global optimum, then employ a Flood-fill algorithm to map the volume around it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @MaximUmansky: true, but I'm still not sure how I should best compute the ravine after that.

Comment: @Nathanael Schilling I would try statistical analysis (multidimensional linear regression) on those data, it should be able to catch a trend such as a ravine there.